# Ручное обновление zImage

Tags: linux, kernel

Скомпилировал ядро zImage, dts и модули для arm linux машины - https://github.com/SolidRun/linux-fslc.
Попробовал заменить все это и запустить машину. Машина запускается, проходит через uBoot и все.

Есть ли подробная документация по поводу замены zImage?

Comment: вероятно, вы имеете ввиду документацию к вашей «машине» и к программе *u-boot*. где искать первое — известно только вам, а второе — [известно всем](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot/Documentation).

Comment: что за машинка? если такая же как у меня - давай объединим усилия

Comment: @eri imx Hummingbird - ядро я сумел сделать. Подключил свои модули. Но сделать то что мне хочется еще не получилось.

Comment: была такая фигня когда версия lzma оказалась новее, чем распаковщик  то ли в ядре то ли в uboot

Comment: @sercxjo а где найти версию распаковщика?

Comment: @Insider, Не знаю, но например для ядра linux-2.6.21 в SDK для ralink прилагался упаковщик lzma версии 4.32.7, а если я использовал системный версии 5.1.0, ядро не грузилось.

Comment: @sercxjo хм, ну это очень странно. собрал ядро на ubuntu - загрузилось но, модули не работали. собрал ядро на самой машине, оно не грузится.